# Change target of links in WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Sometimes when I click on a link, it opens in a new window. Can I prevent this from happening and just load the page in my current window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me (so far):

```
Private Sub browser_NewWindow(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles browser.NewWindow
    e.Cancel = True
    browser.Navigate(browser.StatusText)
End Sub
```

Really simple, *if* the status text is the url (which it always is for the documents I am browsing)

Comment: Hack of the day. I've used it, and I'm happy

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Windows XP SP2 or later, you can [catch the NewWindow3 event to get the target url](http://jiangshengvc.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/how-to-force-popup-window-to-navigate-in-the-same-window-in-a-webbrowser-control/), and after setting the cancel parameter, navigate to the url instead.

For earlier versions of IE you can catch the obsolete NewWindow event with the same handling as documented in [Q185538 How To Cause Navigation to Occur in Same WebBrowser Window](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185538/EN-US/)