# How to Handle/Catch the Link Clicked inside WebBrowser Control in VB.Net 2008

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a WebBrowser control inside a VB.Net 2008 application.

When I click a link inside the WebBrowser, it opens a new Internet Explorer Window. I do not handle the web page so I cannot in any way modify the Target property.

Is there a way in VB.Net to catch the Clicked Link and have it display inside the particular WebBrowser Control?

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379598/change-target-of-links-in-webbrowser-control?

Comment: Yes and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void myWebBrowser_NewWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    myWebBrowser.Navigate(myWebBrowser.StatusText);
}
```